# Which collection should be used to store xml files in memory?

Tags: java, data-structures, collections

This question was posed to me in my interview with Adobe.  I answered hashmap can be used, but he was not satisfied.

## File 1

```
< tag1 >  
  < subtag1 >  
    < subsubtag1 >  
    </subsubtag1 >  
  < /subtag1 >  
< /tag1 >  
< tag2 >  
< /tag2 >
```

*n* numbers of such files (i.e XML files) need to be stored in memory. Write implementation for a java data structure which should be used to store these files in memory with an aim to efficiently perform following operations:

1. access a particular tag in a particular file.
2. access a particular tag in all the files in which that tag exists.

Note:

1. there are millions of files to be stored
2. each file contains millions of tags and each tag may contain millions of subtags

Comment: "(ii) each file contains millions of tags and each tag may contain millions of subtags" Don't tell me you have an exabyte of RAM... This just doesn't sound either *plausible* nor *useful*.

Comment: I'll guess that the interviewer wanted you to use some sort of tree

Comment: possible duplicate of [which java collection should be used to store xml file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18900760/which-java-collection-should-be-used-to-store-xml-file)

Answer (score 0):

I think about `TreeSet`.

> Access and retrieval times are quite fast, which makes TreeSet an excellent choice when storing large amounts of sorted information that must be found quickly.

Something like that:

```
public class Storage{

  private String mTagName;
  private String mAttribute;
  private TreeSet<Storage> mTree; 
}
```

class that contains `TreeSet` of itself. Good for recursion.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that using HashMap was the problem (explained at the bottom). Assuming your XML doesn't contains any attributes than I would go with `HashMap<String, Element>` (TreeMap also would work) where String is XML tag and

```
class Element {
    Set<Files /* or something that represents them */> filesContainingTag;
    Map<String, Element> subTags;
}
```

That way you know what files contain given "tag path" and can get single file.
To access tag in given file just go through this structure by tag and check whether this file is in `filesContainingTag`. Or use Map instead of set if you identify those files somehow (for example by path).

Why Hash* instead of Tree* structures? Because as mentioned - Tree* are good when you need sorted order in iteration. In **most** other cases Hash* are faster and easier to use (it is easier to implement hash function than comparator). The only case where you wouldn't like to use Hash* is when you expect malicious input - when somebody knows what hashing function you are using and would provide data full of collisions.

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be with the notes for the question, which require accessing a large data set. It would definitely would not fit the memory completely, but could partially fit if you unload the unused data. So I would go with either

- `WeakHashMap` which unloads during GC when an item is no longer used in your app
- or Google Guava's [CacheBuilder](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html) which has nice and tunable eviction policies